# Table not found exception in Android Studio

Tags: database, android-studio

I want to add a new table in the exsisting database from another activity. Whenever I try to add new table and insert values that table is not being found. Please help me with the same.

Comment: What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? [How do I ask a good question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might be helpful to improve your question.

Comment: E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: attendance_table
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting col4=d col2=b col1=a col3=c
                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: attendance_table (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO attendance_table(col4,col2,col1,col3) VALUES (?,?,?,?)     ----- This error is coming every time I try to create and insert a new table

Answer (score 0):

You should create class like myDbHelper and then you can define a table in this class.So, you can access the tables by invoking this database class in different activities.

Comment: My application needs two tables which are being created from two different activities, and I have created two different myDBHelper class. So for the first DBhelper its all running good but when I created another Dbhelper class, the table is not getting created in the same database.